# Lyx document format with "subheader"

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I am using an article class in a lyx to produce following format

### Company            Mr XYZ

---

Client name  age <------- "repeated on every page"
Address

Contents

---

footer

I do not want to include repeatative "subheader" in preamble. How can I do it?

---

---

MWE

---

```
%% LyX 2.0.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\newcommand{\lyxaddress}[1]{
\par {\raggedright #1
\vspace{1.4em}
\noindent\par}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LO]{Left header, company name}
\fancyhead[RO]{right heade \\ Mr XYZ}
\fancyfoot{Address}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}


\lyxaddress{I want this\\
CLIENT'S address to be\\
repeated on each page,\\
}

These are my conditions. 
\begin{itemize}
\item I donot want to do this with latex editor. I want to use lyx
\item I am exporting latex file because I do not know how to upload lyx
here
\item I do not like my user to use ``preamble'' on lyx as they may change
it by mistake. That is, I want to write the address on lyx frontend,
but the code to make it repeat on each page can be there in the preamble\@. 
\item Thanks and regard\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post an MWE (that's TeX code, not something you see using Lyx.)

Comment: Please see the MWE

Comment: @user34083 what happens when you use the LyX module by going to Document > Settings > Modules and then "Custom Header/Footerlines" ? Note that you LyX version is old. You should upgrade either to 2.0.6 or 2.1beta2: ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/devel/lyx-2.1/lyx-2.1.0beta2